# How to share ownership of mounted directory on docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am still new at using docker and currently I am planning to do a machine learning training on a supercomputer shared by many user. I have successfully created an image and mount all the necessary data but when I try to run the training, I got permission denied when the code tries to access a .txt file. Here is the error

```
user@701c214f9fa9:/app/sfsnet$ python main_mix_training.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_mix_training.py", line 156, in <module>
    main()
  File "main_mix_training.py", line 132, in main
    with open(args.log_dir+'/details.txt', 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './results//details.txt'
user@701c214f9fa9:/app/sfsnet$ python main_mix_training.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_mix_training.py", line 156, in <module>
    main()
  File "main_mix_training.py", line 132, in main
    with open(args.log_dir+'/details.txt', 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './results//details.txt'
```

I have checked the mounted directory ownership and it should all be mine (dgx_user6) :

```
total 308
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  1271  二  14 05:32  checkmodel.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6   458  二  13 23:51  cropping.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6 12890  二  14 14:03  data_loading.py
drwxr-xr-x 5 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  4096  二  14 04:26  dataset
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6   641  二  13 23:51  generate_dataset_csv.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  2687  二  13 23:51  interpolate.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6    95  二  14 05:32  interpolate.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6     0  二  14 05:32  log_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  6555  二  13 23:51  main_gen_pseudo-data.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  7548  二  13 23:51  main_gen_synthetic_and_full.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  7030  二  14 14:12  main_mix_training.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6 69169  二  14 05:34 'model backup.py'
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  2914  二  14 05:32  model_loading_synchronization.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6 69339  二  14 05:34  models.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  4096  二  13 23:51  pretrained
drwxr-xr-x 2 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  4096  二  14 05:33  __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  3490  二  13 23:51  README.md
drwxr-xr-x 9 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  4096  二  14 05:33  results
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  5090  二  14 05:34  shading.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6   605  二  14 05:34  super_resolution.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6 39867  二  14 05:32 'train backup.py'
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6 32377  二  13 23:51  train.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  1685  二  13 23:51  utils.py
```

I created the container using this command

```
nvidia-docker run -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 -t -i --name coba --mount type=bind,src=/home/dgx_user6/SfSNet/,dst=/app/sfsnet sfs_face
```

part of the container about creating a user

```
# Create a non-root user and switch to it
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
 && chown -R user:user /app
RUN echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/90-user
USER user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user
```

I hope someone can help me resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is located in the results directory :

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './results//details.txt'
```

but only the owner of the directory can write in :

> drwxr-xr-x 9 dgx_user6 dgx_user6  4096  二  14 05:33  results

The image that you use specifies a user which the id differs from the user id of the directory owner on the host .
You can override that behavior by specifying the user (and optionally the group) when you start the container with the `-u / --user` flag ([see run command reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)).
For example that start the container with the user and group id of the host user :

```
docker run  --user $(id -u):$(id -g) myImage
```

Note that ii will work only if the user and group id in the image are the same that those of the user on the host. Default is 1000:1000.
If these `id`s don't match, you should probably find a way to make the user or group id match for files you need to manipulate in both sides.

Comment: Hi, So I have updated my post and there is a part of the dockerfile that change the user to not root is that the problem? And I tried to run with your suggestion and it shows cannot find name for group id 1007  and log in into the container 'with I have no name' can you help me with it?

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I think: the user id on your host is 1007 and I think that the id of the user named "user" in the image is the default (1000:1000).  You have to make them (the host and the image) to use the same user or group id.

Comment: Yes what you thought is correct my container user is 1000:1000 and my host gid = 1007. Do you have a way to change the group id of the "user" container to 1007?

Comment: That is not the right way because it will make your image not portable. That is the host to adapt to. For example change rights on the `results` directory recursively (`chmod -R ug=rw`) to allow group owner to read and write ,change the group owner to a group with the id 1000 and add the host user to that group and it should be ok since by default a `1000:1000` user is used to start the container.